# Connecting to my locally running ftp server written in golang

Tags: server, 22.04, ftp

I am trying to use this [ftpserver](https://github.com/fclairamb/ftpserver) on Ubuntu. I am able to start the server as in below screenshot but I don't know how to connect to it when it's running. I tried **ftp [IP]** command which I found online, since it is running on my laptop I used 127.0.0.1 as the IP and 2121 as port but failed to connect. If I just type ftp I get the `ftp>` prompt but I think it is the ftp server provided by Ubuntu and not the one I started. Please advice how to use the server.

[image]

Comment: Have read the `ftp` Standard (STD 0009) https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc0959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man ftp`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ftp [-46pinegvd] [host [port]]
```

So you should use `ftp 127.0.0.1 2121` and not `ftp 127.0.0.1:2121`.